# use enter to post a comment with facebook comment plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook

Can I use enter to post a comment with comment plugin as the one in Club in facebook?

I'd like to let the users in my site to comment without any extra movement(like move the mouse to click on "commnet")

Is that possible with facebook comment plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: No My Dear it is not possible...................

Comment: BTW, *internet users* are used to that kind of **movement**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has enabled this feature for everyone, so no need for a special plugin.

Unless you are a person like myself that likes using actual paragraphs at times. maybe someone will write a plugin for that.